# How to style a list in CSS such that the background color doesn't go to the end of line

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I'm trying to learn some basic CSS. I'm having trouble styling a list to look like what my instructor has provided for a small practice exercise.

```css
ul#menu li {
  display: block;
  border-block-end: 0px;
  background-color: #66c;
  margin: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #64a;
}

#menu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample Menu Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" title="Q1" href="style2.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sample Menu Page</h1>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="one.html">Page One</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="two.html">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="three.html">Page Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="four.html">Page Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="five.html">Page Five</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="main">
    <h2 id="first">First Section</h2>
    <p>This is the first part of the real content of the page.</p>
    <p>This exercise is mostly about:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><abbr title="Cascading StyleSheets">CSS</abbr></li>
      <li>geese</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Actually, there isn't so much about geese. I just wanted to use a <code>&lt;ul&gt;</code> there.</p>

    <h2 id="next">Next Section</h2>
    <p>I'm really running out of stuff to say here. Oh well, fall back to old standards, I guess&hellip;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried googling people with similar questions and looking at CSS guides but I still can't quite get it.

```css
ul#menu li {
  display: block;
  border-block-end: 0px;
  background-color: #66c;
  margin: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #64a;
}

#menu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: I suggest the task example is wrong - your instructor is setting the ul to have one background color and the li's toanother - BUT - this requires the ul has a padding applied to it (which is common and default in browsers but is often overwritten is style sheets to either remove the padding or set  differently. Therefore if the ul#menu has padding-left: 0 applied to it - the left color goes away. It is always better to not rely on default browser styling and explicitly set the style you want  to the correct selector. There are many ways to achieve that left color applied to the ul or the li's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, make the `ul` a floated element which you place to the right, like this:

```
ul#menu {
  float: right;
}
```

In addition you might want to add `width` to make it look better, and you might want to move it up in the HTML above the `h1` tag to have it floated right at the top like in your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/shpeuo8m/